# How to get list of running VMs from AzureML

Tags: azure-machine-learning-service, azure-sdk-python

I am a beginner with Python and with AzureML.
Currently, my task is to list all the running VMs (or Compute Instances) with status and (if running) for how long they ran.
I managed to connect to AzureML and list Subscriptions, Resource Groups and Workspaces, but I'm stuck on how to list running VMs now.
Here's the code that I have currently:

```py
# get subscriptions list using credentials
subscription_client = SubscriptionClient(credentials)
sub_list = subscription_client.subscriptions.list()

print("Subscription ID".ljust(column_width) + "Display name")
print(separator)
for group in list(sub_list):
    print(f'{group.subscription_id:<{column_width}}{group.display_name}')
    subscription_id = group.subscription_id
    resource_client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
    
    group_list = resource_client.resource_groups.list()
    print("    Resource Groups:")
    for group in list(group_list):
        print(f"    {group.name}{group.location}")
        print("        Workspaces:")
        my_ml_client = Workspace.list(subscription_id, credentials, group.name)
        for ws in list(my_ml_client):
            try:
                print(f"        {ws}")
                if ws:
                    compute = ComputeTarget(workspace=ws, name=group.name) 
                    print('Found existing compute: ' + group.name)
            except:()
```

Please note that this is more or less a learning exercise and it's not the final shape of the code, I will refactor once I get it to work.

Edit: I found an easy way to do this:

```py
workspace = Workspace(
     subscription_id=subscription_id,
     resource_group=group.name,
     workspace_name=ws,
)
print(workspace.compute_targets)
```

Edit2: If anyone stumbles on this question and is just beginning to understand Python+Azure just like I do, all this information is from official documentation (which is just hard to follow as a beginner).
The result from 'workspace.compute_targets' will contain both Compute Instances and AML Instances.
If you need to retrieve only the VMs (like I do) you need to take an extra step to filter the result like this:

```py
if type(compute_list[vm]) == ComputeInstance:
```